# How to add more things to search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to make search script on php. For now it's only searching for serialkey in database, but I want to add more.

```
$search = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `serialkey`, `discordid`, `orderid`, `date` FROM `serials` WHERE `serialkey` LIKE ?");
$search->execute(array("%$q%"));
```

I tried to use

```
$search = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `serialkey`, `discordid`, `orderid`, `date` FROM `serials` WHERE `serialkey` LIKE ? or `discordid` LIKE ?");
```

But it didn't work, just getting error

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Well, did you add the second parameter in your second query? If you wanted to use the same value, you still have to bind it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want to compare multiple columns against the same value, you must bind it the number of times you have used the placeholder. If you have used two placeholders you need to bind the same value twice.

```
$search = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `serialkey`, `discordid`, `orderid`, `date` 
    FROM `serials` 
    WHERE `serialkey` LIKE ? or `discordid` LIKE ?");
$search->execute(["%$q%", "%$q%"]);
```